# Parsing and getting data in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Just want to ask some help on how to parse the data below and get the value.

I have a big file that have a contents like the one below and I want to get the value of floating license expires. as you can see there are 2 space on the left and there is additional space after the license.

```
"Office" v10.8, vendor: Microsoft
  License server: hosts.server.com
  floating license  expires: 01-mar-2019
```

I tried the sample below but it doesn't work.

```
$floatlic =~ /\sfloating license (\s+|)(\w+|_): (\S+)/
```

The result that I want to see is "01-mar-2019" which I can put it in another variable like

```
$floatlicexpiration
```

Comment: What is your desired result string exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
$floatlic =~ /\sfloating license (\s+|)(\w+|_): (\S+)/
$floatlicexpiration = $3;
```

or

```
my ($floatlicexpiration) = $floatlic  =~ /\sfloating license\s+\w+: (\S+)/;
```

Comment: I like the oneliner and it works pretty well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $floatlic = "\"Office\" v10.8, vendor: Microsoft
 License server: hosts.server.com
  floating license  expires: 01-mar-2019
";
$floatlic =~ /floating\s+license\s+expires:\s+(\S+)/sg;
print $1;
```

prints

```
01-mar-2019
```

Is it what you do expect?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Parsing the date after the expires:??

```
/\s+floating license\s+\S+:\s+(\S+)/
```